# How to import node modules from root directory when using node ES Modules feature(.mjs)?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

For example, I have a node project using ES Modules feature which structures like this:

```
- user
-     a.mjs
-     b.mjs
- project
-     c.mjs
-     d.mjs
- main.mjs
```

In a.mjs file I want to import c.mjs file using root path in the way like this:

```
import c from '~/project/c.mjs';
```

but not using relative path like this:

```
import c from '../project/c.mjs';
```

I know I can use `babel` and `babel-plugin-root-import` plugin to achieve this.

But I dont want to use babel, so I am wondering if there is a native solution in node ES Modules can do this?

Comment: `NODE_PATH="." node yourFile.js` *should* work, but for some reason I don't understand it doesn't.